# D3 Sequences Sunburst Animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to D3 and am trying to upgrade [Kerryrodden's sequences sunburst](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426) with zooming and animation:

[image]

I've added the zooming opportunity with the `onclick` event and fully redraw the paths:

```
function click(d)
{
  d3.select("#container").selectAll("path").remove();

  var nodes = partition.nodes(d)
      .filter(function(d) {
      return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
      }) ;

  var path = vis.data([d]).selectAll("path")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter().append("svg:path")
      .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return colors[d.name]; })
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .on("mouseover", mouseover)
      .on("click", click);

  // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
  totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;
}
```

But now I have some troubles with animation. I found many versions of attrTween:

[bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1306365](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1306365),
[bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)),

but none of them work in my case.

[Here's the my CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=111):

[image]

How can I animate the drilldown of this sunburst?

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)? I think it provides all the animations you want.

Comment: Yea, it gives me an error: 
Error: Problem parsing d="function (t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); }"

Comment: Not sure what you mean, the example is working fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution founded:

Added functions arcTween and stash for axis interpolation

```
function arcTween(a){
                    var i = d3.interpolate({x: a.x0, dx: a.dx0}, a);
                    return function(t) {
                        var b = i(t);
                        a.x0 = b.x;
                        a.dx0 = b.dx;
                        return arc(b);
                    };
                };

function stash(d) {
                    d.x0 = 0; // d.x;
                    d.dx0 = 0; //d.dx;
                };
```

and transition() property to the paths initialization:

```
path.each(stash)
     .transition()
     .duration(750)
     .attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

Thanks All.