# How can I use CSV data in a zoomable sunburst chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I have sunburst visualization which basically has the same code structure as the one in [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=111) (that comes from [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733117/d3-sequences-sunburst-animation). I have tried to also include the possiblity to not only zoom-in, but also zoom-back within the sunburst (when clicking into the middle of the sunburst). I have tried the following steps, but none of these have worked so far and I am lost in how to do that (apologies if this is a very easy thing to do, I am very new to JS).

Include at the beginning:

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([0, radius]);
```

Change the arc parameters to:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
.startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
.endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
.innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
.outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });
```

Changed the `arcTween()` function to:

```
function arcTween(d){
var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
  yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
  yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
return function(d, i) {
return i
    ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
    : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
};
};
```

But this doesn't work.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Looks like you retrieved the arcTween code from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373)... Is there a reason you're not using that example as your base? Are you trying to maintain the hover behavior?

Comment: Also a full pen or fiddle of your code would be helpful

Comment: Did the updated answer work for you? If it did please accept it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, Skip Jack, accepting! :) (and sorry for late reply!)

Comment: Haha, no problem thanks... I'm gonna edit the answer a bit more just so it's clear for anyone else that stumbles upon this problem. You might want to change the question to something like "How can I use CSV data in a zoomable sunburst chart?"

Comment: done. :) thanks very much again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still need it but I'm pretty sure [this pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/KppEaP/) answers your question.

The code you posted:

```
...

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
  .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
  .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
  .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); }); 

...
```

all looks correct, as I said in the comment it seems to match Mike Bostock's [Sunburst Example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373). So, without seeing the rest of your code I can't tell you exactly what the problem is.

[The pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/KppEaP/) I created, mentioned above, includes zooming (in both directions), breadcrumbs, and arc fading.

I didn't style it as much as the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=111) you've been using but that shouldn't be too hard to add (not sure what you require). Also, I figure keeping it simple may make it a bit easier to understand. Hope this helps, let me know if you need clarification on something or if you have issues viewing the pen.

**UPDATE**

[This pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/EVbxdw?editors=001), which is a combination of the [one I built](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/KppEaP/) and the other [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=111), starts with CSV data instead of parsed JSON.

The other example used 'size' for the value key instead of 'value'. I changed this in the `buildHierarchy` function and added a unique id to fix the hover behavior:

```
...
childNode = {"name": nodeName, "value": size, id: create_id() };
...
```

The `create_id` function is just something I [found](https://gist.github.com/gordonbrander/2230317) to make unique ids for each item in the tree:

```
function create_id() {
  return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, Skip Jack for helping me! The code I'm playing with is the one from the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=111) I mentioned (I will just be using diff. input data in the same format). Here is a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWLdPy) with the changes I made. I don't understand how to include your suggestions into "my play-pen". I'd be very grateful, if you could help me further.

Comment: Hey no problem, upon further inspection the issue is that whoever wrote the example you were using wasn't using an x or y scale for the arc generation or arcTween functions, instead they were doing these calculations manually. I'm working on tweaking their original to see if I can get it working... However I'd really recommend using my [pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/KppEaP?editors=001) as there is far less code and the formatting is a bit cleaner, especially if you are new to d3

Comment: Aside from the amount of code and structure, there are also other bugs in the [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fcBEe?editors=001) pen, such as if you click on one of the outer rings (the whole chart vanishes)

Comment: Thank you again, Skip Jack! If I would use your code as a starting point, how would I have to use it with a csv data input? I tried in [this pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epeOyw?editors=101), but it doesn't work (strange thing is also, that, when I run it locally, I can see only the inner-most circle).

Comment: I see so it was the CSV part that you needed... I'm editing my answer now with a version of my pen that works with the csv data.

Comment: The issues you saw related the 'size' change (see the edit), as well as d3 not being included on the page. The way the other person included d3 in the html section with a script tag is kind of unconventional for codepen. See this post for more information on including external resources.