# Zoomable sunburst chart in R (SunburstR package)

Tags: javascript, r, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to customize a sunburst chart from different examples that I've found accross the internet. I'm working in R (and Shiny as well) and there is one package that I thought could a good working base, that is SunburstR.

A working example can be viewed [here](http://www.buildingwidgets.com/blog/2015/7/2/week-26-sunburstr).

What I want to have :

- breadcrumbs
- zoomable (forward when cliking a child, and backward when clicking the center)
- fading as you hover the childs it fades other elements except current curent hierarchy
- the percentage in the middle of the chart (or elsewhere relevant) as well as the breadcrumbs. Could be one or the other as long as it is somewhere on the page.
- emphasizing with a bigger circle all around the chart. You'd see the whole circle if hovering the center, and you'd see the current footprint of current hovered element (from startangle to endangle). This is just to help seeing how much what you're hovering is reprensenting compare to the whole thing. This circle would also be the bounding circle, eg when you are exiting it, it cancels the fading since you're not hovering the chart anymore.

I have a little bit of code of everything but struggle to put everything together. Here is where things are currently standing :

- I've got the fading ok.
- I've got the percentages (both center and breadcrumbs)
- I've got the outerRadius defined to allow for the bounding circle around the chart, currently visible at all times. I can't find a way to make it appear when I'm hovering (only the arc of the current hovered element, whole circle when hovering the center) and put it back to `#fff`

  when not hovering anymore this circle.
- I don't have (at all) the abitlity to zoom

Current `sunburst.js` :

```
HTMLWidgets.widget({

  name: 'sunburst',

  type: 'output',

  factory: function(el, width, height) {

var instance = {};

instance.chart = {};

var dispatch = d3.dispatch("mouseover","mouseleave","click");

d3.rebind(instance.chart, dispatch, 'on');

var draw = function(el, instance) {

  // would be much nicer to implement transitions/animation
  // remove previous in case of Shiny/dynamic
  d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-chart svg").remove();

  var x = instance.x;
  var json = instance.json;
  var chart = instance.chart;

  // Dimensions of sunburst
  var width = el.getBoundingClientRect().width - (x.options.legend.w ? x.options.legend.w : 75);
  var height = el.getBoundingClientRect().height - 70;
  var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
  var outerRadius = radius/3.5; // reserved pixels all around the vis

  d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-chart").append("svg")
    .style("width", width + "px") // shouldnt have to do this
    .style("height", height + "px"); // shouldnt have to do this

  // Breadcrumb dimensions: width, height, spacing, width of tip/tail.
  //  these will be the defaults
  var b = {
    w: 0, h: 30, s: 3, t: 10
  };
  //  if breadcrumb is provided in the option, we will overwrite
  //   with what is provided
  Object.keys(x.options.breadcrumb).map(function(ky){
    b[ky] = x.options.breadcrumb[ky];
  });
  /*
  // Mapping of step names to colors.
  var colors = {
    "home": "#5687d1",
    "product": "#7b615c",
    "search": "#de783b",
    "account": "#6ab975",
    "other": "#a173d1",
    "end": "#bbbbbb"
  };
  */

  var colors = d3.scale.category20();

  if(x.options.colors !== null){
    // if an array then we assume the colors
    //  represent an array of hexadecimal colors to be used
    if(Array.isArray(x.options.colors)) {
      try{
        colors.range(x.options.colors)
      } catch(e) {

      }
    }

    // if an object with range then we assume
    //  that this is an array of colors to be used as range
    if(x.options.colors.range){
      try{
        colors.range(x.options.colors.range)
      } catch(e) {

      }
    }

    // if an object with domain then we assume
    //  that this is an array of colors to be used as domain
    //  for more precise control of the colors assigned
    if(x.options.colors.domain){
      try{
        colors.domain(x.options.colors.domain);
      } catch(e) {

      }
    }

    // if a function then set to the function
    if(typeof(x.options.colors) === "function") {
      colors = x.options.colors;
    }
  }
  // Total size of all segments; we set this later, after loading the data.
  var totalSize = 0;

  var vis = d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-chart").select("svg")
      .append("g")
      .attr("id", el.id + "-container")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  var partition = d3.layout.partition()
      //.size([2 * Math.PI, radius * radius])
      .size([2 * Math.PI, (radius - outerRadius) * (radius - outerRadius)])
      .value(function(d) { return d[x.options.valueField || "size"]; });

  // check for sort function
  if(x.options.sortFunction){
    partition.sort(x.options.sortFunction);
  }

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d) { return d.x; })
      .endAngle(function(d) { return d.x + d.dx; })
      .innerRadius(function(d) { return (d.dy == d.y) ? Math.sqrt(d.dy)/3 : Math.sqrt(d.y); })
      .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.y + d.dy); });

  createVisualization(json);

  // set up a container for tasks to perform after completion
  //  one example would be add callbacks for event handling
  //  styling
  if (!(typeof x.tasks === "undefined") ){
    if ( (typeof x.tasks.length === "undefined") ||
     (typeof x.tasks === "function" ) ) {
       // handle a function not enclosed in array
       // should be able to remove once using jsonlite
       x.tasks = [x.tasks];
    }
    x.tasks.map(function(t){
      // for each tasks call the task with el supplied as `this`
      t.call({el:el,x:x,instance:instance});
    });
  }

  // Main function to draw and set up the visualization, once we have the data.
  function createVisualization(json) {

    // Basic setup of page elements.
    initializeBreadcrumbTrail();

    // Bounding circle underneath the sunburst, to make it easier to detect
    // when the mouse leaves the parent g.
    vis.append("circle")
        .attr("r", radius - outerRadius)
        .style("opacity", 0);
        
    var highlight = vis.append("circle")
        .attr("r", radius)
        .style("fill", "#eee");     

    // For efficiency, filter nodes to keep only those large enough to see.
    var nodes = partition.nodes(json)
        .filter(function(d) {
        return (d.dx > 0.005); // 0.005 radians = 0.29 degrees
        });

    var path = vis.data([json]).selectAll("path")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("display", function(d) { return d.depth ? null : "none"; })
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("fill-rule", "evenodd")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colors.call(this, d.name); })
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        //.on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
        .on("click", click);

    // Add the mouseleave handler to the bounding circle.
    d3.select(el).select("#"+ el.id + "-container").on("mouseleave", mouseleave);

    // Get total size of the tree = value of root node from partition.
    totalSize = path.node().__data__.value;

    drawLegend(nodes);
    d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-togglelegend").on("click", toggleLegend);

   }

  // Fade all but the current sequence, and show it in the breadcrumb trail.
  function mouseover(d) {
      
    //highlight.attr("d", arc(d));
    //highlight.style("fill", "#eee");

    var percentage = (100 * d.value / totalSize).toPrecision(3);
    var percentageString = percentage + "%";
    if (percentage < 0.1) {
      percentageString = "< 0.1%";
    }

    var countString = [
        '<span style = "font-size:.7em">',
        d3.format("1.2s")(d.value) + ' of ' + d3.format("1.2s")(totalSize),
        '</span>'
      ].join('')

    var explanationString = "";
    if(x.options.percent && x.options.count){
      explanationString = percentageString + '<br/>' + countString;
    } else if(x.options.percent){
      explanationString = percentageString;
    } else if(x.options.count){
      explanationString = countString;
    }

    //if explanation defined in R then use this instead
    if(x.options.explanation !== null){
      explanationString = x.options.explanation.bind(totalSize)(d);
    }


    d3.select(el).selectAll(".sunburst-explanation")
        .style("visibility", "")
        .style("top",((height - 35)/2) + "px")
        .style("width",width + "px")
        .html(explanationString);

    var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);

    chart._selection = sequenceArray.map(
      function(d){return d.name}
    );
    dispatch.mouseover(chart._selection);

    updateBreadcrumbs(sequenceArray, percentageString);

    // Fade all the segments.
    d3.select(el).selectAll("path")
        .style("opacity", 0.3);

    // Then highlight only those that are an ancestor of the current segment.
    vis.selectAll("path")
        .filter(function(node) {
                  return (sequenceArray.indexOf(node) >= 0);
                })
        .style("opacity", 1);
  }

  // Restore everything to full opacity when moving off the visualization.
  function mouseleave(d) {

    //highlight.attr("d", null);
    //highlight.style("fill", "#fff");    
  
    dispatch.mouseleave(chart._selection);
    chart._selection = [];

    // Hide the breadcrumb trail
    d3.select(el).select("#" + el.id + "-trail")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");

    // Deactivate all segments during transition.
    d3.select(el).selectAll("path").on("mouseover", null);

    // Transition each segment to full opacity and then reactivate it.
    d3.select(el).selectAll("path")
        .transition()
        .duration(250)
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .each("end", function() {
          d3.select(this).on("mouseover", mouseover);
        });

    d3.select(el).selectAll(".sunburst-explanation")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");
  }

  function click(d,i) {
    var sequenceArray = getAncestors(d);

    dispatch.click(sequenceArray.map(
      function(d){return d.name}
    ));
  }

  // Given a node in a partition layout, return an array of all of its ancestor
  // nodes, highest first, but excluding the root.
  function getAncestors(node) {
    var path = [];
    var current = node;
    while (current.parent) {
      path.unshift(current);
      current = current.parent;
    }
    return path;
  }

  function initializeBreadcrumbTrail() {
    // Add the svg area.
    var trail = d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-sequence").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        //.attr("height", 50)
        .attr("id", el.id + "-trail");
    // Add the label at the end, for the percentage.
    trail.append("text")
      .attr("id", el.id + "-endlabel")
      .style("fill", "#000");
  }

  // Generate a string that describes the points of a breadcrumb polygon.
  function breadcrumbPoints(d, i) {
    var points = [];
    points.push("0,0");
    if (b.w <= 0) {
      // calculate breadcrumb width based on string length
      points.push(d.string_length + ",0");
      points.push(d.string_length + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
      points.push(d.string_length + "," + b.h);
    } else {
      points.push(b.w + ",0");
      points.push(b.w + b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
      points.push(b.w + "," + b.h);
    }
    points.push("0," + b.h);

    if (i > 0) { // Leftmost breadcrumb; don't include 6th vertex.
      points.push(b.t + "," + (b.h / 2));
    }
    return points.join(" ");
  }

  // Update the breadcrumb trail to show the current sequence and percentage.
  function updateBreadcrumbs(nodeArray, percentageString) {

    // Data join; key function combines name and depth (= position in sequence).
    var g = d3.select(el).select("#" + el.id + "-trail")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(nodeArray, function(d) { return d.name + d.depth; });

    // Add breadcrumb and label for entering nodes.
    var entering = g.enter().append("g");


    if (b.w <= 0) {
      // Create a node array that contains all the breadcrumb widths
      // Calculate positions of breadcrumbs based on string lengths
      var curr_breadcrumb_x = 0;
      nodeArray[0].breadcrumb_x = 0;
      nodeArray[0].breadcrumb_h = 0;

      entering.append("polygon")
          .style("z-index",function(d,i) { return(999-i); })
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colors.call(this, d.name); });

      entering.append("text")
          .attr("x", b.t + 2)
          .attr("y", b.h / 2)
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "left")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

      // Remove exiting nodes.
      g.exit().remove();

      // loop through each g element
      //  calculate string length
      //  draw the breadcrumb polygon
      //  and determine if breadcrumb should be wrapped to next row
      g.each(function(d,k){
        var crumbg = d3.select(this);
        var my_string_length = crumbg.select("text").node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
        nodeArray[k].string_length = my_string_length + 12;
        crumbg.select("polygon").attr("points", function(d){
          return breadcrumbPoints(d, k);
        });
        var my_g_length = crumbg.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
        curr_breadcrumb_x += k===0 ? 0 : nodeArray[k-1].string_length + b.s;
        nodeArray[k].breadcrumb_h = k===0 ? 0 : nodeArray[k-1].breadcrumb_h;

        if (curr_breadcrumb_x + my_g_length > width*0.99) {
          nodeArray[k].breadcrumb_h += b.h;  // got to next line
          curr_breadcrumb_x = b.t + b.s;     // restart counter
        }
        nodeArray[k].breadcrumb_x = curr_breadcrumb_x;
      });


      // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
      g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + d.breadcrumb_x + ", "+d.breadcrumb_h+")";
      });


      // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
      d3.select(el).select("#" + el.id + "-trail").select("#" + el.id + "-endlabel")
          .attr("x", function(d){
            var bend = d3.select(this);
            var curr_breadcrumb_x = nodeArray[nodeArray.length-1].breadcrumb_x +  nodeArray[nodeArray.length-1].string_length + b.t + b.s;
            var my_g_length = bend.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;

            var curr_breadcrumb_h = nodeArray[nodeArray.length-1].breadcrumb_h + b.h/2;
            if (curr_breadcrumb_x + my_g_length > width*0.99) {
              curr_breadcrumb_h += b.h + b.h/2;
              curr_breadcrumb_x = b.t + b.s;     // restart counter
            }
            bend.datum({
              "breadcrumb_x": curr_breadcrumb_x,
              "breadcrumb_h": curr_breadcrumb_h
            });
            return curr_breadcrumb_x;
          })
          .attr("y", function(d){return d.breadcrumb_h})
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "start")
          .text(percentageString);


    } else {
      entering.append("polygon")
          .attr("points", breadcrumbPoints)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return colors.call(this, d.name); });

      entering.append("text")
          .attr("x", (b.w + b.t) / 2)
          .attr("y", b.h / 2)
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

      // Set position for entering and updating nodes.
      g.attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate(" + i * (b.w + b.s) + ", 0)";
      });

      // Remove exiting nodes.
      g.exit().remove();

      // Now move and update the percentage at the end.
      d3.select(el).select("#" + el.id + "-trail").select("#" + el.id + "-endlabel")
          .attr("x", (nodeArray.length + 0.5) * (b.w + b.s))
          .attr("y", b.h / 2)
          .attr("dy", "0.35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .text(percentageString);

    }

    // Make the breadcrumb trail visible, if it's hidden.
    d3.select(el).select("#" + el.id + "-trail")
        .style("visibility", "");

  }

  function drawLegend(nodes) {

    // Dimensions of legend item: width, height, spacing, radius of rounded rect.
    var li = {
      w: 75, h: 30, s: 3, r: 3
    };

    //  if legend is provided in the option, we will overwrite
    //   with what is provided
    Object.keys(x.options.legend).map(function(ky){
      li[ky] = x.options.legend[ky];
    });

    // remove if already drawn
    d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-legend svg").remove();

    // get labels from node names
    var labels = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) {return d.name})
      .entries(
        nodes.sort(
          function(a,b) {return d3.ascending(a.depth,b.depth)}
        )
      )
      .map(function(d) {
        return d.values[0];
      })
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.name !== "root";
      });

    var legend = d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-legend").append("svg")
        .attr("width", li.w)
        .attr("height", labels.length * (li.h + li.s));

    var g = legend.selectAll("g")
        .data( function(){
          if(x.options.legendOrder !== null){
            return x.options.legendOrder;
          } else {
            // get sorted by top level
            return labels;
          }
        })
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
                return "translate(0," + i * (li.h + li.s) + ")";
             });

    g.append("rect")
        .attr("rx", li.r)
        .attr("ry", li.r)
        .attr("width", li.w)
        .attr("height", li.h)
        .style("fill", function(d) { return colors.call(this, d.name); });

    g.append("text")
        .attr("x", li.w / 2)
        .attr("y", li.h / 2)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
  }

  function toggleLegend() {
    var legend = d3.select(el).select(".sunburst-legend")
    if (legend.style("visibility") == "hidden") {
      legend.style("visibility", "");
    } else {
      legend.style("visibility", "hidden");
    }
  }
};

// Take a 2-column CSV and transform it into a hierarchical structure suitable
// for a partition layout. The first column is a sequence of step names, from
// root to leaf, separated by hyphens. The second column is a count of how
// often that sequence occurred.
function buildHierarchy(csv) {
  var root = {"name": "root", "children": []};
  for (var i = 0; i < csv.length; i++) {
    var sequence = csv[i][0];
    var size = +csv[i][1];
    if (isNaN(size)) { // e.g. if this is a header row
      continue;
    }
    var parts = sequence.split("-");
    var currentNode = root;
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var children = currentNode["children"];
      var nodeName = parts[j];
      var childNode;
      if (j + 1 < parts.length) {
   // Not yet at the end of the sequence; move down the tree.
    var foundChild = false;
    for (var k = 0; k < children.length; k++) {
      if (children[k]["name"] == nodeName) {
        childNode = children[k];
        foundChild = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  // If we don't already have a child node for this branch, create it.
    if (!foundChild) {
      childNode = {"name": nodeName, "children": []};
      children.push(childNode);
    }
    currentNode = childNode;
      } else {
    // Reached the end of the sequence; create a leaf node.
    childNode = {"name": nodeName, "size": size};
    children.push(childNode);
      }
    }
  }
  return root;

};

return {

  renderValue: function(x) {

    instance.x = x;

    // x.data should be a data.frame in R so an Javascript Object of Objects
    //     but buildHierarchy expects an Array of Arrays
    //     so use d3.zip and apply to do this
    var json = [];
    if(x.csvdata !== null){
      json = buildHierarchy(
        d3.zip.apply(
          null,
          Object.keys(x.csvdata).map(function(ky){return x.csvdata[ky]})
        )
      );
    } else {
      json = x.jsondata
    }
    instance.json = json;

    draw(el, instance);

  },

  resize: function(width, height) {

    draw(el, instance);

  },

      instance: instance

    };
  }
});
```

I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150403/how-can-i-use-csv-data-in-a-zoomable-sunburst-chart) where Skip Jack gives [this pen](http://codepen.io/gvenech/pen/EVbxdw?editors=001), but I can't get it to work along with the rest of the sunburstR package... And still this pen would miss the bounding circle and the percentages.

I must emphasize that I'm pretty new to JS so please excuse me if this actually quite easy to solve.

Any help would be welcome, thanks ahead of time for your support !

Comment: @SkipJack you might be able to help on this one ? I have posted a more detailed request specifically to the zoomable task in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43805995/d3-zoomable-sunburst-not-zooming-with-data-from-r).

Comment: You might want to submit that as a feature request here as it's not currently a feature of sunburstR https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/issues